# While loop for password generator in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

From a question I recently posted on here, I managed to create a password generator for an assignment I'm doing. My code for this password generator is as so:

```
from random import shuffle
data = open('randomwords.txt', 'r').read().split()
shuffle(data)

# Creates password from Gadsby text file
password = ''
for x in data[:3]:
    password += x

print password.replace('o', '0')
```

This creates a single password each time the program is run. I need the program to run in a while loop, so I don't have to restart the program every time I want to try a new password.

Also I'd like to be able to output the passwords into another text file, thus creating a wordlist for me to use in this assignment.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid re-using random words in passwords? E.g. when 3 words have been used to make up a password, should these words not be used again?

Comment: No, I don't mind if words are used more than once, I just don't want the same password twice.

Comment: You've identified what you need to do next; what stops you from putting this into a **while** loop?  What stops you from writing the words to a file?  If you don't know how to do those yet, they're both easy enough to look up in the Python documentation or a Python tutorial.

Comment: I've tried to put it in a while loop, couldn't get it too work, not entirely sure what was wrong.